# How to configure task managers for active and standby job managers in a standalone Flink cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a cluster with

3- zookeepers servers
2- Jobmanagers (flink), one active and one standby
4 - Taskmanagers
From flink documentation, taskmanagers when they come up announce themselves. I take that as there is no need to mention task manager host details in flink-conf.yaml in jobmanager. Granted, we need to put all workers in workers file.
Question 1:In flink-conf.yaml, do i need to put jobmanager host details for task manager to register itself, if so, since i have 2 jobmanagers ( active & standby), how can i put the details or host and port?

Question 2: **masters **file - Is this relevant only in taskmanager hosts ? If so, does each taskmanager announces themselves by looking at masters file. If so, what is the relevance of jobmanager.rpc.address and jobmanager.rpc.port parameters in flink-conf.yaml for taskmanager hosts.

I previouly ran one taskmanager and one jobmanager as poc and i put the jobmanager details but now that i have active and standby, i am not sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.